# Continued trouble with Toggling checkboxes with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of code that I recently received assistance from here a few weeks back.

http://jsfiddle.net/49Krx/

My code is currently working just fine as is, when the necessary checkboxes are both unchecked.  Short logic is as such:

If AIR (unchecked by default) is checked, a message will tell you HES has to be check before AIR is checked. If both AIR and HES are checked, and you try to uncheck HES, a message tell you that you can't uncheck HES.

The problems is this: all these values are driven by DB; a few entries may have AIR or HES checked.  When done, the code is thrown out and doesn't even work.  Check Below:

http://jsfiddle.net/AUm7M/1/

AIR is check, but seems like when I check HES, the messages still show up.  I even tried to use prop to get the value of each two checkboxes prior to checking, to no avail.  I'm trying to make sure that the same rules apply, regardless of whether AIR or HES is checked from the database.  example of my attempt below:

```
$(function () {
    $('tr').on('change', '.AIR', function () {
        if (!$(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('.HES').prop('checked')) {
            alert("HES has to be checked if AIR is to be checked.\nPlease go back and check HES.");
            $(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);
        }
    });

    $('tr').on('change', '.HES', function () {
        if (!$(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('.AIR').prop('checked')) {
            if ($(this).closest('td').siblings('td').find('.AIR').is(':checked')) {
                alert("HES1 has to be checked if AIR is to be checked.\nPlease leave HES checked.");
                $(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is add a secondary check on `.HES` to determine if it was already checked before you call `$(this).prop('checked', !this.checked);`

I updated the fiddle with the extra check:

http://jsfiddle.net/AUm7M/2/

That should fulfill your requirement of allowing HES to be checked even if it loads with only AIR checked.

Comment: Justin, your code on the other hand, seemed to work fine.   Thanks!  Will mark as such.

Answer (score 0):

h`.prop('checked')` will give you the property value

And

`.attr('checked')` will give you the attribute value in `HTML`

Use a mix of both..

```
$(function () {
    $('tr').on('change', '.AIR', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $hes = $this.closest('tr.row').find('.HES');
        if (!$hes.prop('checked')) {
            alert("HES has to be checked if AIR is to be checked.\nPlease go back and check HES.");
            $this.prop('checked', !this.checked);
        }
    });

    $('tr').on('change', '.HES', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $air = $this.closest('tr.row').find('.AIR');
        if ($air.is(':checked') && !$this.prop('checked')) {
            alert("HES1 has to be checked if AIR is to be checked.\nPlease leave HES checked.");
            $this.prop('checked', !this.checked);
        }
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gqehu/2/)**

So basically you are checking for the checked attribute to know if it was dumped by the DB. If so the `attr('checked')` will remain true..

Comment: Sushanth, I think I might of missed something with part of your code, as it partially worked but dropped the rules listed earlier.   I'll continue testing just to make sure it's nothing done wrong on my end.

Comment: For what it's worth, your additions to make sense.

Comment: @TinyHaitian.. I don understand.. Can you explain

Comment: I plugged your code here: http://jsfiddle.net/gqehu/  as a result, when both AIR and HES was checked, then I tried to remove HES, the message didn't pop up, though it should. When both are unchecked, then AIR is checked, the message does come up.

Comment: Justin's answer would probably give you the closest to my needs.

Comment: @TinyHaitian.. Did you get it working now.. Or you still need help

Comment: I think I got it it now.   Thanks for your help!  I still need to get used to the attr function, so your suggestion is still appreciated.

Comment: aah.. Edited the code and added a fix to it.. Looks like `.attr` is not required at all .. Need to check for the checked prop of `HES` as well

Comment: Glad to have helped :)